# Rearrange displays according to dpi instead of according to resolution - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, display-settings, dpi

I use two monitors which have the same physical size but different resolutions:

- my laptop screen is 4K (3840 x 2160), 15.6"
- an external portable display, which is FHD (1920 x 1080), 15.6"

In display settings, the 4K screen is at 250% DPI scaling, while the FHD monitor is at 125%, so any window / text / icon / cursor appears as having the same apparent size across both screens.

Nevertheless, Windows 10 will "arrange" the FHD display to be 1/4 the size of the 4K display, as evident on the image:
[image]

So, when moving the mouse cursor from the bottom part of the 4K display to the left, it will get "stuck" at the screen edge! This is totally counter-intuitive for any workflow, since the screens are the same physical size, sit next to each other on my desk and display stuff at the same size.

**QUESTION:** Is there any way to change this behaviour, and have Windows recognize the two displays "the same size"?

Reducing the resolution of my 4K monitor is NOT an option. (Besides needing the 4K for specific tasks, I have 3 different workplaces, and changing the resolution every time is a hassle).

I would accept a solution with third-party software, even with a (moderate) cost.

I currently run Win 2004, if updating to 20H2 can change anything that is a valid option. The external monitor uses DP over USB-C ([ASUS ZenScreen MB16ACM](https://www.asus.com/Displays-Desktops/Monitors/ZenScreen/ZenScreen-MB16ACM/))

Comment: Try installing [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse).

Comment: @harrymc Perfect! That did the trick. It's enough to activate "Allow Corner Crossing". Let me know if you'll put this in an answer, otherwise I'll do it and Wiki it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-source utility
[LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse)
allows to deal with multi-dpi monitor configuration.
It controls the mouse transition between screens to have it appear at the
right physical location.

Described as:

> DPI Aware mouse move across screens for Windows 10
>
> Allows accurate mouse screen crossover location within multi dpi
> monitors environment. It is typically useful when using a 4k monitor
> and a full HD side by side

Here is a review (chosen because of its title):
[LittleBigMouse solved my LittleBigProblem](https://www.markbetz.net/2017/06/29/littlebigmouse-solved-my-littlebigproblem/).

Once installed, activate "Allow Corner Crossing", and press on the "Play" button: the transition of the mouse between the two displays will now be enabled along all the edge of the display.