# Display settings - make a large display larger than a smaller higher resolution one

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a 34" 3440*1440p desktop monitor and a 15" 3840 * 2160 laptop which I connect with the display above the laptop. This works great, however, windows believes that the laptop screen (1) is larger than the desktop screen (2) [#fig 1].

This is annoying as it causes the curser to jump considerably when moving from the bottom of the desktop screen to the top of the laptop screen. Does anyone know of a way to change the size of the displays (as seen by windows) so that the curser could move smoothly from the bottom of the desktop to the top of the laptop [#fig 2]

fig 1 - current sizings

[image: current sizes]

fig 2 - desired sizings

[image: desired sizes]

Thanks,

Comment: Not possible. However, check [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1635999), which may just be good enough for you.

Comment: If you just want to change the order of the screens you may rearrange them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer doesn't care at all about the physical dimensions of the screen, only its pixel dimensions.
Technically, this information is available to it, but it doesn't use it.

As far as crossing between displays is concerned, you can only do this where the pixels match, not the physical displays.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was looking for but at least now I know